# SQL Server View to change structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, tagname

I have an IT guy that has set up a SQL table for me (and is populating it with data)... but the layout is not great...

Instead of a 3 column layout (date, tagname, tagvalue) they have it set with a date column, then all the tag names as column names, and the values are under each column. He doesn't want to change it (this is how we always do it) and doesn't understand the benefits of the other layout (all the same information is there).

I am hoping I can use SQL Server Management Studio to build a view based on this table that will display the data in the format that I want (date, tagname, tagvalue). But I don't have a clue how to do that...

EDIT
I can give you an idea of what the table looks like, but I thought it was pretty clear from above... I would like a solution where I can get table 1 structure into table 2 structure without needing to list every field name (245 and growing)

The current table structure is this...

```
Col1 => LoggedDT (datetime)
Col2 => TagName1 (float)
Col3 => TagName2 (float)
Col4 => TagName3 (float)
...
Col246 => TagName245 (float)
```

So viewing the table would look like this

```
LoggedDT    TagName1    TagName2    TagName3... TagName245
1/1/23 0:00        5          17          42           53
1/1/23 0:01        6          18          40           88
1/1/23 0:02        9          20          37           49
```

Very rarely would a database table be a good design with 240+ columns... and needing to add a new column (or remove a column) every time a tag is added or removed from the required logging.

A MUCH better design would be as such...

```
Col1 => LoggedDT (datetime)
Col2 => TagName  (varchar)
Col3 => TagValue (float)
```

And viewing the table would look like this

```
LoggedDT     TagName     TagValue
1/1/23 0:00  TagName1          5
1/1/23 0:00  TagName2         17
1/1/23 0:00  TagName3         42
1/1/23 0:00  TagName245       53
1/1/23 0:01  TagName1          6
1/1/23 0:01  TagName2         18
1/1/23 0:01  TagName3         40
1/1/23 0:01  TagName245       88
1/1/23 0:02  TagName1          9 
1/1/23 0:02  TagName2         20
1/1/23 0:02  TagName3         37
1/1/23 0:02  TagName245       49
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of the view that your IT guy gave you and what's the structure that you would have?

Comment: And some sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you can't flip the data the way you want, perhaps you're in no position to criticise the current solution. But the usual way of doing "normalized" => "EAV" is a UNPIVOT / values construct. Something like: select somedate, x.* from IT_Table t cross apply (values ('Tag1', CAST(Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),('Tag2', CAST(Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))) x (colName, colValue)

Comment: @siggemannen - I was about to independently post an answer virtually identical to yours, but you had it first. I suggest that you post your suggestion as an answer, because I think that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Alright, added minus the snark!

Comment: @siggemannen I think I am in the position to criticize the table I was given.  I can make his solution work, but with all my other clients, I have set the table up as in the second example above.  I have no idea when the current table design would ever be considered 'good' - I think you can see that...  I will try your solution with a small subset of the table... if it does work, it will still need to be updated each time a column is added or removed.  That is why the second solution would be better for me - and a way to get it into that view without having to list out each column name.

Comment: I am not sure why the votes to close the question.  I am not an SQL Server Management Studio expert, so I came here for help.  It is a legitimate question, one that will help me greatly if I can get some help to figure out a solution.  The actual column names are not as pretty as above... they are more like AG_3601_T, and TV_8250_P... Adding those tags in a varchar columns would be way better than setting them as field (column) names.

Answer (score 2):

To convert "normalized" => "EAV" data, you can use a UNPIVOT / values construct. Something like:

```sql
SELECT  t.somedate
,   x.*
FROM    IT_Table t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES  
        ('Tag1', CAST(Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
    ,   ('Tag2', CAST(Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
    ) x (colName, colValue)
```

Note, that you might or might not need to CAST the values, depending on what kind of columns you got, but usually they are not all the same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a static number of tagname types, you can build a series of UNION ALL statements like:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM
(
SELECT date AS TagDate, 'TagName1' AS TagName, TagValue1 AS TagValue FROM YourTable
UNION ALL SELECT date, 'TagName2', TagValue2 FROM YourTable 
UNION ALL SELECT date, 'TagName3', TagValue3 FROM YourTable 
etc..
) x
```

but siggemannen's answer is more elegant and should be preferred if possible.